# How to delete Dropbox shortcut from Desktop in Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts, dropbox

Recently I uninstalled the Dropbox application from my PC. I also deleted the local folder which was used for synchronization with Dropbox.

However, my Explorer still shows the icon to Dropbox folder, see screenshot.

[image]

When I click on it I get an error "Folder does not exist" - of course, since I deleted this folder. Does anybody know how to get rid of this shortcut? I don't manage it.

Using right-hand mouse button does not offer any "Remove" operation. On my Desktop the icon does not appear, just in "Desktop" Folder at Windows Explorer.

I also checked every users "C:\User\xxxx\Desktop" folder, the shortcut does not exist in any of them.

Comment: I suppose you've tried the standard universal solution of restarting your computer, yes? If not, do that. You could perhaps try creating a new folder on your desktop with the same name, going into it from that Explorer shortcut, closing it and then deleting that folder. Then look again. Kind of a "Look, Explorer; see this folder? Now look how it *disappears*!" approach to try and get the thing to get a grip and refresh itself.

Comment: If that doesn't work you can try creating that folder and *leaving* it there as a hidden folder. If your Explorer isn't set to show hidden files and folders it might hide it then. =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer here: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3348670/windows-folders-gtfo-remove-folders-dropbox-onedrive.html

Open your Registry Editor. Navigate to this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}
```

Then change the value of this DWORD from 1 to 0
`System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree`

For me it solved the problem. I changed also following:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace` -> Delete Key `{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel` -> Value of `{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}` to 0
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}` -> Value of `System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree` to 0

Actually I prefer to change it with from command line:

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /v System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /v System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f    
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f    
reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /f
```

**Update**

After I compared my computer with Registry of another Windows 10 I think it is also save to delete these entries entirely, i.e.

```
reg delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /f
reg delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /f    
reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /f    
reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A} /f
```

Comment: Yeah, search for and delete all "keys" (look like folders) that match the UUID "E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A" in the Registry Editor. (Remember, if you open Registry Editor as Administrator, "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" will be Administrator, not you.)

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to delete this using the command line.

Press the Windows key and R and then cmd in the box to open the command prompt. 
Type cd.. and enter.
Repeat until you get to C:\
Type cd\users(yourname)\desktop (or whatever the location of your desktop is).
Type dir
This will list the files and folders on your desktop.
If you can see the name of the folder type
rmdir dropbox (or whatever the folder is called)

Might work

Good luck!

Comment: Does not work. As I wrote the shortcut does not appear on my Desktop, just underneath Desktop Icon in Windows Explorer.